# Parsing an XML String does not preserve white spaces inside tag

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, tags

I've got an XML String with some tag like this:

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
```

Please notice the white space before the "/>". Due to my specs I've got to preserve this white space, but every time I parse the string, the parser erase that white space.

Here's my code ("line" is the XML String):

```
byte[] base64DecodedResponse = Base64.decode(line);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DecodedResponse);

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(true);

DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = docBuilder.parse(stream);
```

I tried to change parser (Sax instead of javax.xml.parser) but the problem remains. 
Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: You mean that when you write the xml output back to a file, you need to put a space before each />? If this is the case, you maybe need to write your own serializer for xml.

Comment: I get a Base64 file, I decode it, and I obtain my XML String, with all the white spaces in the right places, when I parse the string to get a Document and I print this, I notice that all the white spaces before the "/>" are gone. I hope I made my situation more clear. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How do you print the content of your "document"?

Comment: The Java type Document does not store any formatting. The formatting is introduced in the print method you just stated above. I think you have to craft your own print method which puts the spaces in the right places.

Comment: I use a StringWriter and a Transformer.  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(myDocument), new StreamResult(myStringWriter));  then System.out.println(myStringWriter.toString());

Comment: Print xml before you parse it, if you need 'as is' result. Looks like your xml is digital signed, and before signing it should be canonicalized, and i don't know any canonicalization method witch leave white spaces in tag non-normalized. So, maybe specs is wrong and you don't need this white space.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. Walk through the XML tree (in the `document`) and write the results to lines of string.
2. Use the print method you have and then do a replaceAll that replaces each occurence of "/>" by  " />", e.g.

   ```
   String result = result.replaceAll("\\/\\>", " />");
   ```